# OAuth - Jumblr ¿How to change the account that I'm logged in?

Tags: java, oauth, tumblr

This is the first time that I'm using OAuth throught Tumblr API and although I succesfully log getting the OAUTH TOKEN and OAUTH TOKEN SECRET from this web https://api.tumblr.com/console//calls/user/info I don't know how to get them using the jumblr wrapper to log using any account and put them here:

```
client = new JumblrClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
            OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

Thanks for your help.